# Asp .Net background worker thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web

I am planning to start a background thread in the application start event of an ASP .net website (inside global.asax).

I've read in many places that this is not a good practice, as this thread may crash the whole IIS process or may cause other problems.

I need to start a background thread that connects periodically to another server and update the database, so:

What is the best practice in this case?
Can I just mark the thread as background so that it is stopped automatically when other threads stops? 
and if it is not a good choice to start a thread in this situation what is the best replacement?

Comment: So you read the recommendations that you shouldn't do this, and you want to do it anyway? Make it a Windows Service or Scheduled Task. Don't do this in IIS.

Comment: As @CodeCaster has said, and you already know - this is not good practice. Why leave the website hanging on a thread? (No pun intended). Look into alternatives to do the work which can act independently

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that any background work in ASP.NET can go away without warning when the AppDomain recycles. Windows Services and Scheduled Tasks have less reasons to go away but they, too, can disappear (reboot, deployment, bluescreen, power loss, or god forbid a bug in your code!).

You *must* be able to tolerate any work disappearing. As long as that is the case you can start background work safely.

You can use a timer, or more simply a task that just does:

```
while (true) {
 DoWork();
 await Task.Delay(...);
}
```

Be sure to log errors.

Comment: So is it better to use a Windows Service if I can't tolerate work disappearing?

Comment: Not really because that service can go away, too. See the list in the answer. I usually do all the background work I want to do in a restartable transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Azure. There you could make use of a WebJob or WorkerRole